# Restore the connection to iPhone and run watchkitextension again

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit

I am using Xcode 6.3 and I keep getting the following message even if my phone and watch are both connected (and not locked):

> Restore the connection to "mm24’s iPhone" and run
>   "com.projectname.watchkitextension" again, or if
>   "com.projectname.watchkitextension" is still running, you can attach
>   to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process >
>   com.projectname.watchkitextension.

Even if I reset Xcode, Watch or phone I still get the above. The app seems to install on the devices but the connection with Xcode is not there.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: I got the same error. did you resolve the problem?

Comment: I haven't solved this. However with Xcode 7 and WatchOS2 things seem slightly different and more integrated. I did not touch this for the last few months so I am afraid I can't help much.

Answer (score -2):

I was running into this issue as well and it seems like I was able to solve it by removing the `armv7` attribute of `Valid Architectures` on the WatchKitApp target And the WatchKit extension target.

See this apple forum [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4994?q=Watchkit%20app%20hangs) for more info on it.

This was driving me crazy for about a day and half, but seems to consistently let me build onto my watch for the last 2 hours.

Comment: I don't think so. you can not fix the issue by removing or adding target Armv7